# Is there any difference between $stdin.gets and gets?

Tags: ruby

I am going through Zed Shaw book "Learn Ruby the Hard way" and I wonder is there any difference between **$stdin.gets** and **gets**. If so which one I should prefer?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`gets` is `Kernel#gets`, it first tries to read the contents of files passed in through `ARGV`. If there are no files in `ARGV`, it will use standard input instead (at which point it's the same as `$stdin.gets`)

Comment: So, by using $stdin.gets I eliminate some work? If I know that input will be from standard input instead of Command line argument to script

Comment: Yes, if the input will be from the standard input I guess is better to use $stdin.gets.

Answer (score 1):

By default puts, print, gets etc. work on stdin, and referring to globals (prefixed by '$') is kinda rare. To me it seems like it's idiomatic to not refer to $stdin explicitly.

Update: as Jörg correctly pointed out, gets is sort of smart. According to docs (2.2.0)r:

> Returns (and assigns to $_) the next line from the list of files in
>   ARGV (or $*), or from standard input if no files are present on the
>   command line

Comment: `$stdin.gets` reads from `$stdin`, `Kernel#gets` reads from `ARGF`, that's an important distinction.